# Filter by branch creator using tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-revsets

Is it possible to filter by branch creator using tortoisehg? The filter by author option does not shown commits by others to a branch I have created. Ideally I would like a filter that shows all commits to only the branches that I have created. Thanks for any advice you might have.

Comment: You haven't to ask binary question, because you want not "yes", but such revset as answer

Comment: What's the filter query that you're currently using?

Comment: @Nanhydrin Current filter is "author('zarzarbeast')". It shows all commit made by me, but does not show commits to branches I created that were made by others. I have a lot of branches, some of which have been closed by other developers. So if I could see all commits for only the branches I created, I could verify I have no hanging/stale branches.

Comment: @Zarzarbeast Are these named branches specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct search string:

heads(descendants(children(branchpoint()) and !branch('default'))) and author('Zarzarbeast')

Answer (score 2):

To find everywhere the tree branches:

```
branchpoint()
```

To find the actual new branch first commits themselves:

```
children(branchpoint())
```

To find only the new branches created by you:

```
children(branchpoint()) and author('Zarzarbeast')
```

If these are named branches then we can exclude the default branch:

```
children(branchpoint()) and author('Zarzarbeast') and !branch('default')
```

Then to see the subsequent commits on those branches:

```
branch(children(branchpoint()) and author('Zarzarbeast') and !branch('default'))
```

or to see all the descendants of those branches including commits on the default branch:

```
descendants(children(branchpoint()) and author('Zarzarbeast') and !branch('default'))
```

However, I'm not sure that any of these will give you what you want although they should do exactly what you asked for.
What it sounds like you want to find are unmerged heads on any of these branches, which would be:

```
heads(descendants(children(branchpoint()) and author('Zarzarbeast') and !branch('default')))
```

There's probably a shorter way of doing that but the alternatives I've seen will also give you any branches that have been renamed at the point before they were renamed.

No guarantees that this won't miss something but it should give you a good start.

Comment: 1) `and !` == `-` 2) `branch(children` is OK revset for log and better than `descendants(` (in the light of merged branches)

Comment: Thanks @Nanhydrin!!! This exactly what I was looking for:

branch(children(branchpoint()) and author('zarzarbeast') and !branch('default'))